# Does WithEvents in Visual Basic keep its EventHandlers when changing the reference to the object?

Tags: .net, vb.net, events, event-handling, handles

Does `WithEvents` in Visual Basic keep its `EventHandler`s when changing the reference to the object?

Say I have declared a button, firing events:

```
Private WithEvents _MyButton
```

Now I am subscribing to an event handler:

```
Private Sub _MyButton_Click() Handles _MyButton.Click 
  ' Here I DoClick()
End Sub
```

Will the `DoClick()` function be still called when I change the instance of the button object like shown below?

```
_MyButton = New Button()
```

Comment: I suppose: Yes, but not sure...

Comment: Yes, it will.  When the reference is set, the handlers are automatically added and/or removed as necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This got me curious so I wrote a small console application to visualize what happens if you do this experiment using a timer:

```
Private WithEvents _t As New Timers.Timer With {.Enabled = True}
Private Sub _t_Elapsed(sender As Object, e As Timers.ElapsedEventArgs) Handles _t.Elapsed
    Console.WriteLine("tick")
End Sub

Sub Main()
    ' let it tick for 5 seconds
    Task.Delay(5000).Wait()

    ' destroy the current timer
    Console.WriteLine("destroying this timer")
    _t.Dispose()
    _t = Nothing

    ' add a little pause
    Task.Delay(1000).Wait()

    ' create a new timer
    Console.WriteLine("creating a new timer")
    _t = New Timers.Timer With {.Enabled = True}

    ' let it tick for 5 seconds
    Task.Delay(5000).Wait()

End Sub
```

If you run this code, you will find that it does indeed attach the event handler when the instance of `_t` is replaced. I don't know how it does that, but the magic probably lies in the `Handles` keyword. Anyhow, the answer is yes.